# How to grab form input data using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I have a html form and once a user enters data and click submit I want to grab the entered values using jQuery.**

```
<form class="bmlf-form needs-validation" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="firstName" name="First Name">
  <input type="text" id="lastName" name="Last Name">
  <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" formmethod="POST">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

**Here is the jQuery function I wrote**

```
$(function(){
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function(e){
    var data = {
      FirstName: $("#firstName").val().trim(),
      LastName: $("#lastName").val().trim(),
    };
  });
});
```

**Previous developer wrote this piece of code. I am wondering if it has something to do with my code ? as its using the same form id "*.bmlf-form*" or I can just ignore it.**

`// This onload event is required for the bootstrap event to work`

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  $(".bmlf-form").on("submit", event => {
    event.preventDefault(event);
    const values = $(event.target).serializeArray();
    console.log(values);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please confirm the click event is happening or not by `adding console.log("Clicked!!!");` inside the click event.

Comment: Checked it already by adding a js alert box. Its getting fired. Can i check by printing the values using console.log ?

Comment: ya please go ahead & check for data

Comment: It worked Thanks.

Comment: That's great news. Can you please elaborate the solution, so that it will help others as well

Answer (score 1):

Pass the selector type.Since this is id selector you need to put `#`.Also if you are using ajax use `e.preventDefault()`

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(e){
```

Comment: If i use "e.preventDefault()" its not checking for validation